# Using ng-repeat to create nested tables

Tags: angularjs

The first snippet shows my desired output:

```html
<table>
 <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">Name</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Place</th>
    <th colspan="3">Date1</th>
    <th colspan="3">Date2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>DD</th>
    <th>MM</th>
    <th>YYYY</th>
     <th>DD</th>
    <th>MM</th>
    <th>YYYY</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>US</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>09</td>
    <td>2017</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

In this snippet I tried to implement the creation of the table. `$scope.tableData` holds the data. I use the attribute `tableHead` to initialize the table head. In my usecase `var1`, `var2` and `var3` are always present but `var3`'s nested attributes can be variable. That means that there sometimes might be a `var5_4` or a `Date3`. Furthemore the data doesn't contain always all attributes which are specified in tableHead. Since this issue I'm looking for a way to create my table.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.tableData = {
    'tableHead': {
      'var1': 'Name',
      'var2': 'Place',
      'var3': [{
        'var4': 'Date1',
        'var5': [{
            'var5_1': 'DD'
          }, {
            'var5_2': 'MM'
          },
          {
            'var5_3': 'YYYY'
          }
        ]
      }, {
        'var4': 'Date2',
        'var5': [{
          'var5_1': 'DD'
        }, {
          'var5_2': 'MM'
        }, {
          'var5_3': 'YYYY'
        }]
      }]
    },
    'tableData': [{
      'var1': 'Test',
      'var2': 'US',
      'var3': [{
        'var4': 'Date2',
        'var5': [{
          'var5_2': '09',
          'var5_3': '2017'
        }]
      }]
    }]
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<table>
<tr>
<th rowspan="2">Name</th> <!--always present, no need for ng-repeat-->
<th rowspan="2">Place</th> <!--always present, no need for ng-repeat-->
<th ng-repeat="x in tableData.tableHead.var3" colspan="x.var5.length" >{{x.var4}}</th>
</tr>
<!-- how to create the second table head row !? -->
<!-- how to create the data rows !? -->

</table>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to change the $scope.tableData format, you can try something like that:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.header = [
    [{
      name: 'Name',
      rowspan: 2
    }, {
      name: 'Place',
      rowspan: 2
    }, {
      name: 'Date1',
      colspan: 3
    }, {
      name: 'Date2',
      colspan: 3
    }],
    [{
      name: 'DD'
    }, {
      name: 'MM'
    }, {
      name: 'YYYY'
    }, {
      name: 'DD'
    }, {
      name: 'MM'
    }, {
      name: 'YYYY'
    }]
  ];

  $scope.data = [{
    name: 'Test',
    place: 'US',
    date2: {
      mm: 09,
      yyyy: 2017
    }
  }];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="thRow in header">
      <th ng-repeat="th in thRow" colspan="{{th.colspan}}" rowspan="{{th.rowspan}}" data-ng-bind="th.name"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="d in data">
      <td data-ng-bind="d.name" />
      <td data-ng-bind="d.place" />
      <td data-ng-bind="d.date1.dd" />
      <td data-ng-bind="d.date1.mm" />
      <td data-ng-bind="d.date1.yyyy" />
      <td data-ng-bind="d.date2.dd" />
      <td data-ng-bind="d.date2.mm" />
      <td data-ng-bind="d.date2.yyyy" />
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: But what if there might be next time one more date in the data `d.date3.dd` and `d.date3.mm` and `d.date3.yyyy`or even a far more. This solution is too rigid.

Comment: So there is no limit of _dateX_ elements number?

Comment: Yes, there is no limit